# Insert Into a Table Across Linked Server From SP Using Openquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, openquery

I want to send data across from one server to another, I wish to improve my performance and wondered if OpenQuery is a good route to go down?

I tried to do something like this;

```
INSERT INTO OPENQUERY (SERVERNAME, '(SELECT Num1, Num2, Num3 FROM [DBName].[dbo].TableName)')
(Num1, Num2, Num3)
SELECT Num1, Num2, Num3
 FROM #Temp
```

However this returns the error

```
The provider indicates that conflicts occurred with other properties or requirements.
```

I don't understand this as the query does run fine and produce the required results without OpenQuery...

Could any of you advise me on this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
INSERT INTO tablename 
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET
    ('SQLOLEDB', 
     'Trusted_Connection=yes;Server=SERVERNAME','SELECT Num1, Num2, Num3 FROM [DBName].[dbo].TableName)')
```